# What is a phantom in the dark, ghost in the light, and spirit midways?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Another riddle;

> Phantom in the dark,
> Ghost in the light,
> And spirit midways.
> What or who am I?

What is the answer?

Comment: This is a very vague and short riddle, and could be many things. Could you maybe add in another verse or something to make this a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be

> smoke

Reasoning:

> Phantoms, ghosts, and spirits can all be used to refer to the same thing, which is a non-corporeal being. While smoke does contain solids, it also resembles ghosts in the way it's not entirely physical, and how whispy it is, also sharing similar colours to how ghosts are depicted. The fact that synonyms are used for how it is in the dark, the light, and midways might refer to the fact that it still maintains those ghost-like qualities no matter what the light condition is.